# Redirect Shopify Password Page to original URL

Tags: redirect, shopify, password-protection

I have a shopify store which is password protected and always will be. I want to be able to have links in an email I send out and after the store user has entered the password on the password page it will direct to their original clicked link not the home page.

Be very glad of any help on this.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried until this point?

Comment: @drip - I have only tried the below which didn't work. I didn't really know where to start.
In login-form | <input class="devRedirect" type="hidden" name="checkout_url" value="/collections/all" />